# Running Docker Desktop on AWS EC2 Virtual Machine (Windows server 2022)

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-desktop, windows-server-2022

Im trying to set up docker desktop on my EC2 virtual machine running windows server 2022. But the program just crashes a few seconds after it starts. Im guessing virtualization is not enabled. Any suggestions to what could be the problem?

I tried to install Hyper-V but that is not working either.